pre-allocate memory for a string
I was trying to pre-allocate x memory to see what happens when the user uses more than the quantify that I pre-allocate. So, I wrote the code but nothing happened.
I wrote this version:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    char *s = malloc(4);

    if (s == NULL) // check se está vazia
    {
        return 1;
    }
    printf("s: ");
    scanf("%s", s);
    printf("The input is: %s\n", s);
    free(s);
    return 0;
}

And this version:
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char s[4];
    printf("s: ");
    scanf("%s", s);
    printf("Input: %s\n", s);
}

Even if I pre-allocate 4 bytes and the user puts a string that uses 6 bytes, for example, the program works normally. I want to know why. What am I doing wrong? Maybe I missed some concepts?

There can definitely be some more space after the allocated string that you can fill without getting the program to crash. So in your case you are just lucky. This is still not something you should do. The proper way to read the string with scanf is using %3s (note that 3 is 4 - 1 because you need space for the final \0 terminator).

Undefined behavior is undefined. In other words, when you have UB anything can happen.
